# How to download support dll

Tags: support

I've found the necessary answer on my question. But answer provide the name of sitecore support dll. How I can download necessary files if I know support dll name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try searching for it here:

https://kb.sitecore.net

The dll will have a reference number associated with it Sitecore.Support.xxxxx.dll.

For example: https://kb.sitecore.net/SearchResults#term=442487

If you can't find it just raise a ticket with Sitecore and they will provide you with the dll.

Also recently released is this Github project containing source code for support fixes

https://github.com/SitecoreSupport

Answer (score 3):

Sitecore no longer provides support dll on  https://github.com/SitecoreSupport. Having recently tried to access a support dll on github.

If you try and access a dll using a path you've been given previously you will receive a 404.

I asked a question relating to this on slack and Rob Earlam, Technical Evangelist @ Sitecore answered: “We don’t have Support DLL’s on GitHub anymore, if you need a specific fix then you’ll need to open a Support ticket yourself and make the request there.”

Comment: A note for anybody looking at this answer. This was changed again, as for Jan 2019 anybody can access most of patches on https://github.com/SitecoreSupport (except for certain that cover security vulnerabilities).